# How to create Instance for IAntiForgery Interface and IHttpContextAccessor in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, antiforgerytoken

Have created a class which is gonna Create AntiforgeryToken as well as Validate the Token,

Created a Method In which have Created property for IAntiForgery using that property just accessing the GetAndStoreTokens which have parameter as httpContext which is passed using the property created by IHttpContextAccessor, at Run time am getting Null instance for the property created for IHttpContextAccessor and IAntiforgery, I know I need to create a instance but didn't get which concrete class to be instantiated for the IHttpContextAccessor and IAntiforgery

Code What I have Tried

```
        private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    private void generateToken(){
       antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

`IHttpContextAccessor` can be made available for dependency injection to the constructor of your class by using the `AddHttpContextAccessor()` method when registering services in your `Startup` class ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)).

Similarly, `IAntiforgery` will be made available for dependency injection if you call `AddAntiforgery`, which *should* be available to you anyway if you're using ASP.NET Core MVC, Razor Pages or Signal R ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration)).

Comment: this AddHttpContextAccessor and AddAntiforgery 
 is available in IServiceCollection, but my scenario is different I need create instance from a normal class

Comment: You could make an `IHttpContextAccesor` by using `HttpContextAccessor` (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0199dcc4cdfd7b15a6c9b8b3b080e26517775532/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs#L11), but that doesn't mean you'll be using the same one the rest of your application is (because they'll get it from DI). The default `IAntiforgery` implementation is internal and only accessible through DI (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0199dcc4cdfd7b15a6c9b8b3b080e26517775532/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/DefaultAntiforgery.cs#L19). Your use case isn't supported.